# Append tags based on CLASS to an specific ID container

Tags: jquery

I'm a designer with HTML/CSS knowledge, but I'm new to jQuery.

I've managed to make a simple accordion work, but I need help populating it with content from a database.
I have a list of items with a group assigned to them, and I need to make a tab for each group.

I used the group's name in the database as an ID for the container and as a class for each item in order to "link" them.
I made a demo work like this:

HTML

```
<div id="accordion">
  <h3>GROUP 1</h3>
  <div class="gr" id="group1">
    <ul></ul>
  </div>
  <h3>GROUP 2</h3>
  <div class="gr" id="group2">
    <ul></ul>     
  </div>
</div>

<ul>
  <li class="group1">Item A</li>
  <li class="group2">Item B</li>
  <li class="group1">Item C</li>
  <li class="group2">Item D</li>
</ul>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".group1").appendTo($("#group1 ul"));
    $(".group2").appendTo($("#group2 ul"));
});
```

How could I achieve the same result for an undefined number of items and groups with unknown names?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) + [`.attr("class")`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".gr").each(function() {
    const group = $(this).attr("id");
    $("." + group).appendTo("#" + group + " ul");
  });
});
```